# how I can define variable name with " write " command in fortran

Tags: fortran90

I need to define a variable name for different files inside a Fortran code, while I 'm using this commands

```
open(unit=5,file="plot.sm")
write(unit=zbin_str,fmt='(f5.2)') zbin

plotname="LF_z"//zbin_str//".ps"

write(5,"dev postencap"  plotname) 
write(5,"toplabel LF for",//zbin_str//)
```

I'm receiving these errors :

```
Syntax error, found '//' when expecting one of: ( * <IDENTIFIER> <CHAR_CON_KIND_PARAM> <CHAR_NAM_KIND_PARAM> <CHARACTER_CONSTANT> ...           
 write(5,"toplabel LF for",//zbin_str//)

error #6355: This binary operation is invalid for this data type.   [PLOTNAME]            
     write(5,"dev postencap"  plotname) 

An arithmetic or LOGICAL type is required in this context.          
     write(5,"dev postencap"  plotname)
```

How I can define the available name inside the Fortran code??
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Neither of these lines

```
 write(5,"dev postencap"  plotname) 
 write(5,"toplabel LF for",//zbin_str//)
```

is well-formed; that's what the compiler is trying to tell you.

Beyond that, I'm not sure what you are trying to do or, therefore, how to fix it.  Unless you use keywords your Fortran compiler will understand the 2nd argument in a `write` statement to be the format specifier in which you want to present the output.  I can't see how either `"dev postencap"  plotname` or `"toplabel LF for",//zbin_str//` can be made into a valid format specifier.  Perhaps what you want is

```
 write(5,'(a32)') "dev postencap"//plotname
 write(5,'(a32)') "toplabel LF for"//zbin_str
```

Anything more would be based on guesswork.  If this doesn't answer your question explain it more clearly if you can.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. it worked to solve those errors, but I have an other error now. I'm producing a catalog with some information via fortran and I want to plot the my diagrams in different bins so I will have many plots which I need to change their name while I'm going to the next bin,                                          output statement overflows record, unit -5, file Internal Formatted         Write              , what dose this error mean?

Comment: do j=1,b
mag(j)=mag_min+(j-1)*bin
magup(j)=mag(j)+bin   
do jj=1,total
if (z(i).le.redshift(jj).and.redshift(jj).le.zup(i)) then fi=fi+1/v    
end do 
write(4,'(i5,2x,f20.8,2x,f9.4)')kk,fi,mag_average                             end do 
close(4)          
open(4,file='luminosity_func.asc')
open(unit=5,file='plot.sm')
write(unit=zbin_str,fmt='(f5.2)') zbin
plotname="LF_z"//zbin_str//".ps"
write(5,"dev postencap"//plotname) 
write(5,'("luminosity_func.asc")') 
write(5,'("read {fi 2 mag 3 }")')
write(5,"toplabel LF for"//zbin_str)
close(5)
call system ("sm < plot.sm")

Comment: Oh good grief, surely you don't expect anyone to read a comment like that.  I suggested you post another question, not a comment.